# Java Error Handling - Is this the best way to do this?

Tags: java, error-handling

I have an error in a console program I'm making, in which I can't seem to handle an error.

If a user enters an incorrect input type (such as an float where an int goes), they are reprimanded, and the program functions (even though the program shuts down, it does it *my* way):

```
while(!scanner.hasNextLong()){
                System.out.println("You entered something bad..  Why do you hurt me?");
                System.out.println("*Calcumatastic dies, and I hope you feel remorseful*");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException f) {
                    f.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

If a user enters, for example, a zero as a variable that cannot equal zero (due to division of zero), the user is reprimanded, and life still goes on, and the program still functions:

```
while (b == 0) {
            System.out.println("Did you even read the instructions??  You cannot divide by zero!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Second Integer: ");
            b = scanner.nextLong();
        }
```

However, if a user attempts to divide by zero, THEN enters an incorrect input type, the program crashes.  What am I doing wrong?  I've tried entering a try/catch- while loop as I did in other instances, but it doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
System.out.println("Second Integer: ");
        while(!scanner.hasNextLong()){
            System.out.println("You entered something bad..  Why do you hurt me?");
            System.out.println("*Calcumatastic dies, and I hope you feel remorseful*");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
        b = scanner.nextLong();
        while (b == 0) {
            System.out.println("Did you even read the instructions??  You cannot divide by zero!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Second Integer: ");
            b = scanner.nextLong();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean, 'crashes'? Do you get an exception and a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to perform a division by zero, an `java.lang.ArithmeticException` is thrown and when you try to read a long and user enters something that can't be parsed, `InputMismatchException` is thrown (possibly what you call a "crash").

Error is occurring because you are using `b = scanner.nextLong();` when user enters 0 without checking if user entered a valid long value.

Here is your code adjusted:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    long b = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Second Integer: ");

        b = readLong(scanner);

        if (b == 0) {
            System.out.println("Did you even read the instructions??  You cannot divide by zero!");
            System.out.println();
        }
    } while (b == 0);
}

private static long readLong(Scanner scanner) {
    if (!scanner.hasNextLong()) {
        System.out.println("You entered something bad..  Why do you hurt me?");
        System.out.println("*Calcumatastic dies, and I hope you feel remorseful*");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return scanner.nextLong();
}
```

Comment: Correct, the InputMismatchException was thrown, it was not a crash.  Sorry for the error in terminology, i'm a bit of a noob.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. We're here to help. Don't forget to upvote or downvote the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your input validation appears to be consecutive. That is, you check for invalid input and then you check for zero values. You probably want to do both every time there is input.

You probably want to check for all error cases in a single loop. Something like:

```
System.out.println("Second Integer: ");
// a loop wrapping your other validation checks
while(scanner.hasNext()){ // while there is input:
    while(!scanner.hasNextLong()){ // check for non-long input
        System.out.println("You entered something bad..  Why do you hurt me?");
        System.out.println("*Calcumatastic dies, and I hope you feel remorseful*");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
    b = scanner.nextLong();
    while (b == 0) { // check for non-zero input
        System.out.println("Did you even read the instructions??  You cannot divide by zero!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Second Integer: ");
        b = scanner.nextLong();
    }
}
```